# What does the (+++) operator do in Text.ParserCombinators.ReadP (Haskell)

Tags: parsing, haskell

I am having trouble with the symmetric choice (+++) operator in the ReadP package.

https://www.haskell.org/cabal/release/cabal-1.22.8.0/doc/API/Cabal/Distribution-Compat-ReadP.html

As I cannot find many examples of the ReadP lib on the internet I've just been trying some things.

I noticed that the biased choice works as expected. Favoring parsing the left and if it fails choose the right parser.

`fmap Just (munch1 dianaFloat) <++ return Nothing`

If I insert the symmetric choice operator. The algorithm doesn't finish.

`fmap Just (munch1 dianaFloat) +++ return Nothing`

If I let the lefthand fail they both yield the same result:

`fpail) <++ return Nothing`

==

`fpail) +++ return Nothing`

So my question is, what use is the (+++) operator, as it doesn't seem to finish when both succeed in parsing.

Comment: By the way the source can be found in base. https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Text-ParserCombinators-ReadP.html

Comment: I can't reproduce the non-termination. `readP_to_S (fmap Just (munch1 (== 'c')) +++ return Nothing) "c"` produces `[(Nothing,"c"),(Just "c","")]`.

Comment: Hmm.. I see in your small example that it doesnt choose but just returns both results. In the large file I'm parsing however nothing happens.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `+++` operator can backtrack to give you both results when either
possibility can work.  Here's a simple example:

```
> readP_to_S (many (string "aa" +++ string "a") <* eof) "aaa"
[(["aa","a"],""),(["a","aa"],""),(["a","a","a"],"")]
```

If you used `<++` here you would only get the first result.

Your example could also work fine in some circumstances, allowing two
possibilities (with different amounts of input left over):

```
> readP_to_S (fmap Just (munch1 (=='a')) +++ return Nothing) "aaa"
[(Nothing,"aaa"),(Just "aaa","")]
```

My guess is that you are using it in some context where it's possible
for it to keep choosing `return Nothing` repeatedly, like inside a
`many` or a recursion.  Since this doesn't consume any characters it
might be trying to produce a parse which involves choosing "return
Nothing" repeatedly forever and never getting any further through the
input.

Alternatively it could be producing an infinite number of parses, for
example one where it uses `return Nothing` once, another where it uses
it twice, and so on.  Although in this case it would usually be happy
to start printing the infinite list of parses, so you'd probably know
about it.